# Not your Parsha, Can you get an Aliyah

Tags: halacha, torah-reading

If someone is from Eretz Yisrael and is visiting America while the parshios are not the same. Can one get an Aliyah?

Please source your arguments

Comment: Shouldn't be worse then getting an aliya at main minyan after going to hashkama

Comment: Why not? Reading the Torah on Shabbos is merely a *chovas ha’tzibbur*; an *oleh* is never *mechuyav* in a particular *parsha* and so can’t be “invalidated” as an *oleh* just because a different *parsha* is being read in his hometown.

Comment: The fact that no Rishonim discuss this, despite having had many more local variations of ways of splitting up parshas over the calendar than we have, indicates it's not a problem.

Comment: @DoubleAA I totally understand that. I just wanted mekoros for such a contention. Not the lack of them. Or at least inferences from other ideas

Comment: Moderators: Why the deleted comment containing an important topical reference?

Comment: Perhaps this would have been a bit more of a concern at the time that each oleh read from the Torah himself. Perhaps, that scenario warrants the question - if it is not someone's own parsha and he is the one fulfilling the mitzvah of public reading, can one who is "not obligated" b/c he's reading the "wrong parsha" fulfill the obligation of the congregation? Currently, having a different Torah reader, I suspect, does not pose any type of problem.

Comment: O.C. does mention rules of what happens if the reader has read the wrong section. However, It seems the "wrong section" applies to what the cong. should hear, not the Oleh.

Comment: it’s interesting that there’s a difference when it’s cHol Hamoded for the Israeli in Chutz when it’s 2nd day Yom Tov we don’t give him an aliya?

Answer (score 2):

As concerns public Torah readings, one does not have a personal parsha, rather, the congregation does. The [Shulchan Aruch HaRav](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/which-parsha-is-it/) website brings the following:

> Traveling from Israel -
>
> ***Kerias Hatorah*** for Ben Eretz Yisrael in Chutz Laaretz when Parshiyos
>   are not aligned: If one traveled from Eretz Yisrael to the Diaspora
>   in a week that Eretz Yisrael is one Parsha ahead of the Diaspora, as
>   occurs in certain years starting from the Shabbos after Pesach or the
>   Shabbos after Shavuos, and thus in the Diaspora they will repeat the
>   reading that he heard in Eretz Yisrael, then he is obligated to hear
>   the Parsha a second time.
>
> **Shnayim Mikra:** If one traveled from Eretz Yisrael to the Diaspora
>   in a week that the Diaspora is reading the Parsha that was read the
>   previous Shabbos in Eretz Yisrael he is not required to repeat
>   Shnayim Mikra of that Parsha , even though he is required to hear
>   the reading of the Torah.
>
> **Aliyos: There is no issue with a Ben Eretz Yisrael getting an Aliyah to the Torah, even though he is holding by the next Parsha.**
>
> Chitas: If one traveled from Eretz Yisrael in a week that Eretz
>   Yisrael is reading a different Parsha than the Diaspora, then on the
>   day of arrival he is to stop learning the Chumash with Rashi for his
>   Parsha, and study the Chumash with Rashi for the Parsha of Eretz
>   Yisrael, until that days Aliyah."

Comment: Thank you so much, i just wish he sourced his reasoning to say there is no issue.

Comment: [Rav Asher Weiss](https://www.torahbase.org/%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%95%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A1%D7%93/) quotes rishonim that say it is a personal obligation (that just has to be done with a minyan ).